# Xamarin Forms Custom Content View (Composite Control) Implicit Style Error

Tags: xamarin.forms

This seems like something that should be simple but I have been unable to locate a solution for it.

I have the following defined in my sample project:

**ReadOnlyField.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ContentView x:Name="ReadOnlyFieldContentView" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.Views.ReadOnlyField">
    <StackLayout Spacing="4">
        <Label FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReadOnlyFieldContentView}, Path=HeaderFontSize}" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReadOnlyFieldContentView}, Path=HeaderText}" />
        <Label FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReadOnlyFieldContentView}, Path=DetailFontSize}" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReadOnlyFieldContentView}, Path=DetailText}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**ReadOnlyField.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TabbedPageDemo.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

    public partial class ReadOnlyField : ContentView
    {
        #region Fields

        private static readonly BindableProperty DetailFontSizeProperty;
        private static readonly BindableProperty DetailTextProperty;
        private static readonly BindableProperty HeaderFontSizeProperty;
        private static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        static ReadOnlyField()
        {
            DetailFontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DetailFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(ContentView), 12.0);
            DetailTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DetailText", typeof(string), typeof(ContentView), null);
            HeaderFontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("HeaderFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(ContentView), 14.0);
            HeaderTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(ContentView), null);
        }

        public ReadOnlyField()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public double DetailFontSize
        {
            get => (double) GetValue(DetailFontSizeProperty);

            set => SetValue(DetailFontSizeProperty, value);
        }

        public string DetailText
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(DetailTextProperty);

            set => SetValue(DetailTextProperty, value);
        }

        public double HeaderFontSize
        {
            get => (double) GetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty);

            set => SetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty, value);
        }

        public string HeaderText
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(HeaderTextProperty);

            set => SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:v="clr-namespace:TabbedPageDemo.Views" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.Views.Page2">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="v:ReadOnlyField">
            <!-- <Setter Property="HeaderFontSize" Value="14" /> -->
            <!-- <Setter Property="DetailFontSize" Value="12" /> -->
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollView1" Padding="4">
        <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout0">
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 1" DetailText="Detail 1" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 2" DetailText="Detail 2" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 3" DetailText="Detail 3" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 4" DetailText="Detail 4" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 5" DetailText="Detail 5" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 6" DetailText="Detail 6" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 7" DetailText="Detail 7" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 8" DetailText="Detail 8" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 9" DetailText="Detail 9" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 10" DetailText="Detail 10" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 11" DetailText="Detail 11" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 12" DetailText="Detail 12" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 13" DetailText="Detail 13" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 14" DetailText="Detail 14" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 15" DetailText="Detail 15" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 16" DetailText="Detail 16" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 17" DetailText="Detail 17" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 18" DetailText="Detail 18" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 19" DetailText="Detail 19" />
            <v:ReadOnlyField HeaderFontSize="14" DetailFontSize="12" HeaderText="Header 20" DetailText="Detail 20" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

If I uncomment either of the two lines in the `<Style>` element, I get the following error:

```
Can't resolve *propertyName* on ReadOnlyField
```

What I would like to do is use an implicit style such as the one I am attempting to define so that I don't have to specify property values many times over.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The error is caused by the **Access Modifiers**.

Please change `private` to `public`.

**Change:**

```
private static readonly BindableProperty DetailFontSizeProperty;
    private static readonly BindableProperty DetailTextProperty;
    private static readonly BindableProperty HeaderFontSizeProperty;
    private static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty;
```

**To:**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DetailFontSizeProperty;
    public static readonly BindableProperty DetailTextProperty;
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderFontSizeProperty;
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextProperty;
```

And you could define an `style` using the `x:Key attribute` like below. The property should match the BindableProperty you defined.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyFieldStyle" TargetType="v:ReadOnlyField">
        <Setter Property="HeaderFontSize" Value="14" />    
        <Setter Property="DetailFontSize" Value="12" />
        <!--<Setter Property="HeaderText" Value="Header1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="DetailText" Value="Detail"></Setter>-->
    </Style>
```

And use the style.

```
<v:ReadOnlyField Style="{Binding StaticResource ReadOnlyFieldStyle}" HeaderText="Header 1" DetailText="Detail 1"></v:ReadOnlyField>
        <v:ReadOnlyField Style="{Binding StaticResource ReadOnlyFieldStyle}" HeaderText="Header 2" DetailText="Detail 2"></v:ReadOnlyField>
```

Result:
[image]